# What does it mean when a SQL Server procedure parameter is null-able and also has a default?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I ran into a situation today where the following procedure from a SQL Server 2016 instance wasn't backwards compatible with SQL Server 2008 R2.

My question is, what is the functionality difference between these two procedures?

Note the additional `NULL` after the type `[int]`, this does not compile on SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AmazingProcedure1
    (@Value int NULL = NULL) 
AS
BEGIN   -- PROCEDURE
    SELECT 'Dummy Value'
END     -- PROCEDURE
```

This procedure compiles on SQL Server 2008 R2 all the way up through 2016. Note that I can still pass a NULL to the procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AmazingProcedure2
    (@Value int = NULL) 
AS
BEGIN  -- PROCEDURE
    SELECT 'Dummy Value'
END    -- PROCEDURE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql

> NULL | NOT NULL Determines whether null values are allowed in a
>   parameter. NULL is the default

for SQL Server 2008R2, it does not support the `NULL | NOT NULL` . The NULL after equal sign is the default value. which means if the parameter is not supplied, it will takes NULL value.

Comment: Ah, so NULL is the default, meaning I can still pass a NULL even when nullability has not been explicitly defined. Thanks!